# PostGIS error while adding feature: no result buffer

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

Can anyone explain to me the following error and possible fixes?  I am using QGIS 2.12.3 to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.5 database.

[image]

What confuses me is that I was able to add a feature and save, but then the second feature I tried to add threw this error.  I've had this happen on previous days, only with QGIS 2.12.  When I use 2.8 I do not get this problem (but some other issues with default values arise with 2.8 so I would prefer to use 2.12)

Any clues as to what's going on?

Update for more detail:
I have a postgis table of streets, and another table of signs (mostly freeway navigation signs) which are used for a navigation app.  The signs table does not have any geometry and is in the format (from_link, to_link, navigation instructions, sign_ID).  The from/to links are both ID numbers from the streets layer.

I never have any issue with adding features to the streets layer, only on the signs layer.  This is consistent for more than one layer (I have a separate table for each city) which leads me to believe there may be something weird going on with the lack of geometry?

Only constraint on the sign table is a primary key on the sign_ID

And here is the SQL used for creating the table.  You can ignore most of the fields, they are just various instructions for our navigation code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.austin_signs
(
  "Source_LinkID" bigint,
  "Destination_LinkID" bigint,
  "Sign_ID" bigint DEFAULT 0,
  "Seq_Number" character varying(255),
  "Exit_Number" character varying(255),
  "Exit_LangCd" character varying(255),
  "ExitNum_Tr" character varying(255),
  "Alt_Ex_Num" character varying(255),
  "Branch_RouteID" character varying(255),
  "BrRte_Tr" character varying(255),
  "Branch_RouteDir" character varying(255),
  "Sign_TextType" character varying(255),
  "Sign_Text" character varying(255),
  "Lang_Code" character varying(255),
  "SignTxt_Tr" character varying(255),
  "Trans_Type" character varying(255),
  "Toward_RouteID" character varying(255),
  "TowRte_Tr" character varying(255),
  "Straight_On" character varying(255),
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('austin_signs_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT austin_signs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I am the owner of the database so I don't think it is a permissions issue

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this new feature (and how you're creating it)  that you're trying to insert to the table? Even better would be posting the WellKnownText of the feature so others can try as well. Does your table have any constraints?

Comment: I've got the same issues, in my case I can add and edit feature, but today when I try to add feature I got this error. fyi, I don't change anything in my system.

Comment: Try adding a field with a geometry type to your table, maybe your function tries to create it, and you can not insert the result of creating geometry into the table ...