# QGIS save postgis table error : no result buffer

Tags: qgis, postgis

I've a polygon layer on PostGIS, and when I try to add featureS using QGIS it gets error when I save the edit.

Here is the error notification "no result buffer".

[image: Here, the error picture]

I found a similar case here : [PostGIS error while adding feature: no result buffer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181940/postgis-error-while-adding-feature-no-result-buffer). But it doesn't give me the answer to solve it. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does anyone have a way to solve this issue without restarting? I don't want to lose the work I've done, so restarting is a problem.

Comment: @Alicia What worked for me was opening the affected layer's Properties dialog then selecting OK.  After doing this the save worked fine.  There may be other factors at play (i.e. I restarted the DB beforehand though to no effect).  If I can reproduce this I'll post a proper answer.  (My reasoning behind opening the Properties dialog was to coax QGIS into refreshing its DB metadata).  I'm using QGIS 2.6.0.

Answer (score 11):

I have had a similar error. From the QGIS PostGIS log:

```
Unable to access the "gvkort"."modelomr" relation.
            The error message from the database was:
            no result buffer.
            SQL: SELECT * FROM "gvkort"."modelomr" LIMIT 1
```

I suspect this was due to a database timeout after a long meeting not using QGIS with an open pg connection. After restarting QGIS the problem went away - and not before. This happens a lot in pgadmin, but have never seen it in QGIS before.

Comment: I had the same error, so following this advice I closed the QGIS project down and opened it up again, and this time it worked, no error. Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. **QGIS 2.8.15**, **PostGIS 2.4.2**. I tried to log it in PostgreSQL with the highest level of registered events. The only message that refer to the error, when I click "Save" button in QGIS, is `Connection error: SELECT nextval('myschema.mytable_id_seq'::regclass) returned 1 [FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command]`

Comment: this error still persisting and it's almost 2020